# How to import a header from a txt file?

Tags: excel, import, excel-2019

I have this data (I pasted it from a text file) https://imgur.com/gallery/cHWLVYD

And I have another text file with the data of the header (with the font size and the type of information). But I don't understand how to put that data as a header ? I'm using Windows 10 with Excel 19

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I would add that as a tag instead of "arrays","header" and "row" (these are very generic terms). The [Text Import Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) is probably what you are after (select the appropriate version "Office 2010 - Office 2016" vs "Newer versions"). The "Transform data" button from the wizard will give you plenty of options.

Comment: Hello! I have 2019

Comment: Since your data has a CSV format you can also save the data in a file with the `.csv` extension. You can use Notepad to create the file (assuming you are on Windows), pay attention to the file extension when saving the file. Excel can open and edit CSV files, you can then resave the Excel workbook as a XLSX file.

Comment: Hey! I found how to put the info! But it creates a column with the font sizes and a column with the text type (text, date, time...) thats not what I want :O

Comment: Looks like that data is part of your input (it is in your example). Just delete the columns you do not need? If you still have trouble, then you might want to edit and expand your question (consider adding a screenshot).

Comment: hey Sander! I just updated the post!

Comment: I've just seen your edited post. It's as I thought . You can copy the column and paste special , transpose (horizontaly ). onto your new or current header.    p.s. they weren't font sizes. Those were column widths.  Going to sleep.shattered.